# Template Inheritance odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I am developing in odoo 8, and my task is to create menu links on left side of the page and when you click the link, the template having html should be shown. below are the codes applied so far:

my template is : external id ( menu_item.test )

```
<template id="receivePO">
            <div >
                <div align="center" >
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                </div>
                <form role="form" t-attf-action="" method="POST">
                    <div align="center">
                        <table >
                            <tr>
                                <td>Enter Name :</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="po"/></td>   
                            </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td>Enter Password :</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="passwd" id="po"/></td> 
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><button name="submit" type="submit" >Submit</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
</template>
```

The above template is in Module A.

I have created a new module ( Module B) to create menu item in warehouse menu and if clicked on the menu item login it should display the above template.

in Module B, the menu items are:

```
<record id="action_view_menu" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">MenuItem</field>
        <field name="res_model">Module B Model Name</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="menu_item.test" />
 </record>

    <menuitem id="menu_sub_sales_menuitem" parent="stock.menu_stock_root" name="Warehouse Management" sequence="1"/>
    <menuitem id="menu__sub_menuitem" parent="menu_sub_sales_menuitem" name="Processes" sequence="1" groups="base.group_no_one" />  
    <menuitem id="menu__menuitem" parent="menu__sub_menuitem" name="Login" sequence="1" action="action_view_menu" />
```

I have tried using using ir.ui.view in model also, but got errors.
Can someone help me regarding this. Also, Login template in other Module will be processing login and going into other templates. I have to show those templates on click of the submit button.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure, but looks like you mixed "model" and "module" terms. `<field name="res_model">Module B</field>` Should be not a `Module B`, but corresponding model.

Comment: Hi Shpionus, It was a typo, res_model is model name. i have edited it.